# how to show javascript text editor value from database

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am new to java script, for my project i provide a java script text editor to create their own  text with some alignments, after entering the value i provide a button to save that text in database. If suppose they want to edit the previous saved text, at that time i fetching the data from database, but javascript text area is not come. I am using editor.js i tired the below code but no luck.

```
<td><textarea class="txtEditor" name="body" ><?php echo $title1; ?></textarea></td>
```

Comment: this question is entirely different, i know ow to show text area value, file value, but i am asking ho to show java script text area value from database